# Convert dictionary of objects with parents to a nested dictionary with children

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, hierarchy

I have a dictionary of entities having a parent-child relationship, obtained after parsing the parents of each entities in a file. 
I end up with a dictionary having the following structure, where each element have a complete list of all its parents. Sample dictionary:

```
data_dict = {
    '1388004': {'content': '13', 
                'parents': ['1280', '1279', '90964', '1385', '91061', '1239', '1783272', '2', '131567', '1'], 
                'name': 'foo'}, 
    '1895753': {'content': '11', 
                'parents': ['46913', '45401', '356', '28211', '1224', '2', '131567', '1'], 
                'name': 'bar'}, 
    '642227': {'content': '11', 
               'parents': ['82986', '1903409', '91347', '1236', '1224', '2', '131567', '1'], 
               'name': 'baz'}, 
    '89373': {'content': '27', 
               'parents': ['768507', '768503', '976', '68336', '1783270', '2', '131567', '1'], 
               'name': 'zab'}, 
    '81406': {'content': '21', 
               'parents': ['872', '194924', '213115', '28221', '68525', '1224', '2', '131567', '1'], 
               'name': 'oof'}, 
    '796027': {'content': '12', 
               'parents': ['410829', '410830', '4892', '4891', '147537', '716545', '4890', '451864', '4751', '33154', '2759', '131567', '1'], 
               'name': 'ofo'}, 
    '589342': {'content': '16', 
               'parents': ['3027', '2759', '131567', '1'], 
               'name': 'raz'}
    }
```

The `parents` list represents **all the parents of a given entity in reversed order**. It meand that for `589342`, the hierarchy is as follows: `1` (the root of my tree) contains `131567`, that contains `2759`, that contains `3027`, that itself contains `589342`.

The output I would need is a list or dict of all entities and their **children** (not parents like I currently have), and would ideally looks like something like (let's ignore the `content` and `name` fields for now):

```
{'id': '1', 'children':[{
    'id':'131567', 'children':[
            {'id':'2759', 'children':[...]}, 
            {'id':'2', 'children':[...]}
        ]
    }, 
    ...
    ]
}
```

Any idea on how to achieve that are welcome! If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: No, the `parents`list is a list of all parents (the parent of the objects and its parents, until rot is reached). Sorry if my explanation was not clear.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the parents are *sound*? Is it possible that one parent list is `[a,b,c]` whereas the other is `[a,d,c]`?

Comment: Yes there will always be only one possible path to reach an object.

Comment: Other attributes like `content` and `raz` are not important?

Comment: They can be ignored for now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert your `data_dict` into lists of "anchestors":

```
parents = [[k] + v["parents"] for k, v in data_dict.items()]
```

Then, you can iterate those lists in reverse order and add new entries to a dict accordingly:

```
root = {}
for hierarchy in parents:
    current = root
    for node in reversed(hierarchy):
        current = current.setdefault(node, {})
```

The result format is a bit different...

```
{'1': {'131567': {'2': {'1224': {'1236': {'91347': {'1903409': {'82986': {'642227': {}}}}},
                                 '28211': {'356': {'45401': {'46913': {'1895753': {}}}}},
                                 '68525': {'28221': {'213115': {'194924': {'872': {'81406': {}}}}}}},
                        '1783270': {'68336': {'976': {'768503': {'768507': {'89373': {}}}}}},
                        '1783272': {'1239': {'91061': {'1385': {'90964': {'1279': {'1280': {'1388004': {}}}}}}}}},
                  '2759': {'3027': {'589342': {}},
                           '33154': {'4751': {'451864': {'4890': {'716545': {'147537': {'4891': {'4892': {'410830': {'410829': {'796027': {}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

... but should be easy to translate afterwards, e.g. like this:

```
def translate(d):
    return [{"id": k, "children": translate(v)} for k, v in d.items()]
```

Comment: Awesome! I liked Willem's solution too, but it seems he deleted it... Thanks!